# Search for big number of words in long string

Tags: c#, regex, string, list

Let's say I have the list of the key words, about 30-40 and I'd like to find all/any of these words in very long text, let'say about few thousands words.
Only idea I have - use multiple regular expression and add matches to the `List<string>`.
Is there some better solution?

P.S. These key words may be coma separated as well as one by one across the text.
P.P.S. Just for example this is text from Wikipedia.

I need to find words: "Shakespear", "English", "Language".

> William Shakespeare (/ˈʃeɪkspɪər/;[1] 26 April 1564 (baptised) – 23 April 1616)[nb 1] was an English poet, playwright, and actor, widely regarded as the greatest writer in the English language and the world's pre-eminent dramatist.[2] He is often called England's national poet and the "Bard of Avon".[3][nb 2] His extant works, including some collaborations, consist of about 38 plays,[nb 3] 154 sonnets, two long narrative poems, and a few other verses, the authorship of some of which is uncertain. His plays have been translated into every major living language and are performed more often than those of any other playwright.[4]
>   Shakespeare was born and brought up in Stratford-upon-Avon. At the age of 18, he married Anne Hathaway, with whom he had three children: Susanna, and twins Hamnet and Judith. Between 1585 and 1592, he began a successful career in London as an actor, writer, and part-owner of a playing company called the Lord Chamberlain's Men, later known as the King's Men. He appears to have retired to Stratford around 1613 at age 49, where he died three years later. Few records of Shakespeare's private life survive, and there has been considerable speculation about such matters as his physical appearance, sexuality, religious beliefs, and whether the works attributed to him were written by others.[5]
>   Shakespeare produced most of his known work between 1589 and 1613.[6][nb 4] His early plays were mainly comedies and histories and these works remain regarded as some of the best work produced in these genres. He then wrote mainly tragedies until about 1608, including Hamlet, King Lear, Othello, and Macbeth, considered some of the finest works in the English language. In his last phase, he wrote tragicomedies, also known as romances, and collaborated with other playwrights.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: what do you want your result to look like? words with indexes where they were found? Or just a yes/no?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This can be done with regex. The engine will compose a trie. The only problem are the boundries, but that can be handled via lookarounds.

Comment: No this one. That's example.

Comment: Do you want me to put here all pages of Wikipedia to be long enough?

Comment: The more general solution is the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). I presented a C# implementation a few years ago. See [Aho-Corasick revisited](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=869). You can approximate it with regular expressions, but the approximation is not perfect. See [my blog entry](http://blog.mischel.com/2014/03/19/searching-for-strings-in-text/) for more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a list of keywords that are contained in a string, something like this would work:

```
var results = myKeywordList.Where(k => myBigLongString.Contains(k));
```

You can also use `Any`, for a boolean result, or `Count` for the number instead of `Where`

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ChiUvx) displaying the results.

If you want to make it case insensitive use `ToLower` on the long string and `k`

Comment: As I understand k is array of key words? How can add each matching words to the List<string>?

Comment: k is each keyword in the list.  So it will search your string for each keyword.

Comment: @andrey.shedko `results` will be all the keywords that exist in your text.

Comment: Probably that's solution that I'm looking for. Let me try.

Comment: @andrey.shedko - Amazing, but LINQ is still a dog slow way of doing this. Even if the source string contained multiples of the element being searched where it stops after the first find, the voluminous overhead of resetting the search position for each element makes it a dog slow way of doing it. The overhead is exponentially larger the larger number of keywords. Regex engines use a trie for its alternations where it scans the sample text just for those start characters, then tests alternation text. It does this in a single pass. LINQ is great for a more complex situation, but not for this.

Comment: @paqogomez - Maybe a speed concern was not in the OP's direct question, but it's obviously the 800 lb. gorilla where a large amount of kewords and large test subjects are at play.

Answer (score 1):

You could use positive and negative lookaround assertions like below.

```
@"(?<!\S)(?:Shakespeare|English|Language)(?!\S)"
```

Add `(?i)` modifier in order to do a case insensitive match.

```
@"(?i)(?<!\S)(?:Shakespeare|English|Language)(?!\S)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zA6zB5/2)

> P.S. These key words may be coma separated as well as one by one across the text.

```
@"(?i)(?<=^|[,\s])(?:Shakespeare|English|Language)(?=[,\s]|$)"
```

Comment: Thanks. This probably will do the trick as well, but I'm prefer LINQ way.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for IndexOf

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Perls Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof)

```
int pos = mytext.IndexOf("Shakespear");

if(pos >= 0){ /*Shakespear found*/ } else {/*Shakespear not found*/}
```

Using IndexOf will give you the starting position which will enable you to use the [Substring](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring) method to extract string and manipulate them however you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a subexpression with the escaped word list.
like

(pseudo-code)
`string rx_list = "(" + RregEscape( MyArray.join("|") ) + ")";`

Then, Dot-Net can do expression yes/no conditionals.
Using that info you can wrap the 'rx_list' subexpression into
a boundry arbitration expression.

`string regex_final = @"(?(?=\w)\b|\B)" + rx_list + @"(?(?<=\w)\b|\B)";`

Example regex string result:

```
 # (?(?=\w)\b|\B)(Shakespeare|English|Language)(?(?<=\w)\b|\B)

 (?(?= \w )           # Conditional, is next letter a word
      \b                   # yes, word boundry
   |  \B                   # no, not word boundry
 )
 (                    # (1 start)
      Shakespeare
   |  English
   |  Language
 )                    # (1 end)
 (?(?<= \w )          # Conditional, was prev letter a word
      \b                   # yes, word boundry
   |  \B                   # no, not word boundry
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for such extended answer.

Comment: @andrey.shedko - No problem. By far this is the fastest way to do it.